# I cannot download Xcode from the App Store

Tags: xcode, app-store

I just don't know what is happening but I can't download Xcode.

I did click on the update button on the App Store, but it did nothing.

What should I do?

Comment: I have the same issue.  and when I go to purchased it just says waiting.  Then after a really long time of waiting it said installing... and the install time started to bounce between 3 and 15 minutes.

Comment: btw, if it means you can't install your app on your device, (because you need the latest version of xcode to do this) it is programming question.

Comment: @AndrewPaulSimmons By that logic, "help, I forgot my password" is a programming question. If something prevents you from programming, that doesn't mean it's a suitable topic.

Comment: Vote to re-open since it can be reproduced today again :)

Using Apple's dev tools and systems just results in a bigh "sigh, what are they doing over there?" Failbuckets.

Comment: In my case, the downloading started at moment when I removed the previous version.

Comment: Try here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390162/download-install-xcode-9-1-beta-or-xcode-9-version-without-premium-developer/44390183#44390183

Comment: I reproduced it today.  The download icon spun for 20 seconds or so before stopping with no further feedback.  The solution was to go to System Preferences -> Software Updates, and allow Mac OS to update itself.  Apparently X-Code won't install if your OS is a major version behind.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Maybe it is just temporary bug… wait some time, and try again. Or try to restart the Mac App Store application.

But, if you need it right now, and nothing helps - you can download a dmg file with latest Xcode from:
https://developer.apple.com/downloads

Comment: The downloads in this link do not seem to work anymore (at least if I'm trying to download xcode 9.0.1)

Comment: It works for me for 9.2

Comment: Works for x code 10

Comment: Awesome! Works for me with x code 10.1. Thank you very much!

Comment: It still works for me.

Comment: New link to find all Xcode downloads (use search on the right) https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ https://developer.apple.com/download/ is still valid but leads to AppStore when you try to download app.

Comment: Apple seems to make it more difficult to us. New link is https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=xcode

Comment: insane how this still happening in 2022

Answer (score 27):

The problem is that there is an issue updating Xcode. The update process is stuck so when you press update nothing really happens.

The solution is:

1. delete Xcode (put it in the trash).
2. search for Xcode in the Mac App Store
3. do a fresh install of Xcode.  (The button in the Xcode page in the Mac App Store will say "install" instead of "update" because you removed Xcode in step 2.)

Cheers!

Comment: 2018 - problem still persists and solution does work.

Comment: 2019 - problem still persists and solution does work

Comment: If you want to download Xcode faster - download it from Apple site, unpack and replace old application with new one. https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Comment: Putting Xcode in the trash, even emptying the bin, does NOT signal the app store that Xcode is no longer installed. It still says "update" on the store page.

Comment: 2020 - problem still persists and solution does not work

Comment: 2021 - problem still persists and solution does not work

Comment: 2022 - problem still persists and solution does not work- Mackbook Air M1